# How to close app from any screen that developed on flutter

Tags: android, flutter

My flutter application has 3 Screens

1. Login
2. Register
3. Home

I want that when user register or login in my app then he will go the home screen (I have done it) and when He press back button the app will close automatically I have used Willpopscope(Flutter Widget) but it didnt worked. It took me back to my login or register which I opened first.

Comment: Your issue is not much clear. Can you explain more

Comment: I have on register one login and one home screen. If user login or register I save the data in my firestore database and second time when he come to app the app automatically opened the home screen(I have done these things). I want that when user is on home screen and He pressed the back button then he will not go to my register or login page(My issue). I want to when he press back button from home screen app automatically close.

Comment: Please see "[ask]" and the linked pages and "[mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: You want to stop going back to login or register page from home page right?

Comment: yeah bro you got my point right now

Answer (score 2):

To exit app from any screen. you can use `SystemChannels.platform.invokeMethod('SystemNavigator.pop')`

code snippet

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
...
FlatButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  SystemChannels.platform.invokeMethod('SystemNavigator.pop');
                },
                child: Text('Yes'),
              )
```

full example code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        // This is the theme of your application.
        //
        // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
        // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
        // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
        // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
        // or simply save your changes to "hot reload" in a Flutter IDE).
        // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
        // is not restarted.
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the home page of your application. It is stateful, meaning
  // that it has a State object (defined below) that contains fields that affect
  // how it looks.

  // This class is the configuration for the state. It holds the values (in this
  // case the title) provided by the parent (in this case the App widget) and
  // used by the build method of the State. Fields in a Widget subclass are
  // always marked "final".

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    _exitApp(context);
    setState(() {
      // This call to setState tells the Flutter framework that something has
      // changed in this State, which causes it to rerun the build method below
      // so that the display can reflect the updated values. If we changed
      // _counter without calling setState(), then the build method would not be
      // called again, and so nothing would appear to happen.
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  Future<bool> _exitApp(BuildContext context) {
    return showDialog(
          context: context,
          child: AlertDialog(
            title: Text('Do you want to exit this application?'),
            content: Text('We hate to see you leave...'),
            actions: <Widget>[
              FlatButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  print("you choose no");
                  Navigator.of(context).pop(false);
                },
                child: Text('No'),
              ),
              FlatButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  SystemChannels.platform.invokeMethod('SystemNavigator.pop');
                },
                child: Text('Yes'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ) ??
        false;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // This method is rerun every time setState is called, for instance as done
    // by the _incrementCounter method above.
    //
    // The Flutter framework has been optimized to make rerunning build methods
    // fast, so that you can just rebuild anything that needs updating rather
    // than having to individually change instances of widgets.
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by
        // the App.build method, and use it to set our appbar title.
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        // Center is a layout widget. It takes a single child and positions it
        // in the middle of the parent.
        child: Column(
          // Column is also a layout widget. It takes a list of children and
          // arranges them vertically. By default, it sizes itself to fit its
          // children horizontally, and tries to be as tall as its parent.
          //
          // Invoke "debug painting" (press "p" in the console, choose the
          // "Toggle Debug Paint" action from the Flutter Inspector in Android
          // Studio, or the "Toggle Debug Paint" command in Visual Studio Code)
          // to see the wireframe for each widget.
          //
          // Column has various properties to control how it sizes itself and
          // how it positions its children. Here we use mainAxisAlignment to
          // center the children vertically; the main axis here is the vertical
          // axis because Columns are vertical (the cross axis would be
          // horizontal).
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I will reply you after checking it. It worked or not.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using `Navigator.push` when redirecting from login to home. This push to navigator stack which you can pop go back to previous one. If you want to stop going back you need to use `Navigator.pushReplacement`. This will replace the current route.